# Live stream extensions in android

Tags: android, stream, live

Is there any live stream extension without of m3u8 ? Because android MediaPlayer doesn't support this format. In any case you must use Vitamio. So Is there any way to stream m3u8 with MediaPlayer in android. Any code is not working in this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this answer: [Video Streaming over wifi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373608/video-streaming-over-wifi/20373668#20373668)

Then if u want to see the live streaming in android phone then include vlc plugin inside your application and connect through real time streaming protocol(RTSP)

```
Intent i = new Intent("org.videolan.vlc.VLCApplication.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity");
                               i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);                
                               i.setData(Uri.parse("rtsp://10.0.0.179:8086/"));
                               startActivity(i);
```

If u have installed vlc on your android phone, then you can stream using intent and pass the ip address and port no. as shown