# Video Streaming over wifi?

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi, wifi-direct, android-bluetooth

How do I stream a video from my android smartphone to my Laptop(windows 7) without using any app? Any suggestions? A brief explanation would really help. And, I mean "streaming" and not file transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use this feature without using any app,what you need to do is to program a socket client that sends the video to the server which is connected over wifi .try googling about TCP sockets in android

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following link .
https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/
you will get full source code for wifi streaming which u can see both on a browser in laptop as well as vlc media player also (rtsp). And also u can see in another mobile/tablet using vlc plugin